# Text width not working in markdown files?

Tags: vimrc, textwidth

I use vim pencil which has a setting called `vim.opt.textwidth = 80`.

I also have this in my init.vim (neovim): `let g:pencil#textwidth = 80`

But when I am writing in markdown files, the text takes up the whole window until the end of the screen. It doesnt go to the next line after 80 chars.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `:verb set tw` when the markdown file is open?

Comment: The `let g:pencil#textwidth = 80` look more like a command for `init.vim` instead of `init.lua`

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. This is in my init.vim, not init.lua.

Comment: `:verb set tw` output is `textwidth = 0`. "last set from /path/to/pencil.vim"

Comment: Well, there you go then. Your textwidth is not being set to 80; it's being reset by pencil plugin. Open an issue in the plugin's GitHub repo.